# Why is my memory usage keep increasing in processing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am processing a bunch of csv files which are loaded into pandas DataFrames. I am processing them in multiprocessing in Python:

```
with Pool(10) as pool:
    pool.starmap(self.process_data, all_df_data)

def process_data(self, df_data):
        ......
        for column in columns:   
          rel_df = pd.DataFrame(relations.values())
          rel_df = rel_df.drop_duplicates()

          rel_df.to_csv(relation_output_file, sep='\t', index=False)

     df_data.drop(rel_label, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

In `process_data`, it doesn't strong anything into any global variables, and after each `df_data` is processed, all contents in it are dropped as the last line shows.

Why does the memory usage keep increasing?

Comment: You probably are serializing a lot more than you think you are when calling map on an instance method from inside the instance.

Comment: @CJR Could you be more specific about the point?

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. There is not enough here to go on;. For example, we need to see how `all_of_data` is created.

Comment: Not really. The problem isn't in the code you posted. I would suggest refactoring process_data so that it's a function and not an instance method.